# How do I directly download OpenImages from Sage Maker notebook to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I am using [openimages API](https://pypi.org/project/openimages/) to download a certain subset of classes defined under `labels_array`. This code easily downloads the classes required to a folder in Sage Maker instance.

```
from openimages.download import download_dataset
for labels in labels_array:
    download_dataset(
        data_location, 
        ["{}".format(labels)], 
        annotation_format="pascal"
)
```

But I want to download it to S3 bucket. I found this solution example:

```
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join('billing', 'billing_sm.csv')).upload_file('billing_sm.csv')
```

I unable to figure out how to use this solution with the openimages API on Sage Maker. Could someone help me out understand this?

Answer (score 0):

In a Sage Maker notebook instance create a python notebook and use the following code. This code will download a list of desired labels out of the 600 open images labels. As soon as one category is downloaded it is moved to S3 bucket and deleted from the notebook instance.

```py
import os
import shutil
import openimages
from openimages.download import download_dataset

# create a directory where all the images will be downloaded in Sage Maker
os.mkdir('openImages/')

# create a list of the labels with either the first letter capital or all lowercase
labels_list = ["football","ambulance","ladder","toothbrush"]

# to download the list of labels to a S3 bucket
for labels in labels_list:
    download_dataset("openImages/", 
    # remove `.capitalize()` if you have the first letter of label in uppercase
                     [labels.capitalize()], 
                     annotation_format="pascal")
    # to move the files from sage Maker to S3
    os.system('aws s3 cp --recursive openImages/ s3://open-images/')
    # remove the folder from Sage Maker once the files are copied to S3
    shutil.rmtree("openImages/{}/".format(labels))
```